# How to verify that private generic method was called?

Tags: unit-testing, typemock, typemock-isolator

I need to check whether private generic method was called with particular parameter type.

(Just stop thinking of telling me it's a bad practice to test private methods.)

```
Isolate.Verify.NonPublic.WasCalled()
```

has no overloads for specifying type parameters.

Is such verification possible?

**Update**

Since 7.5.2 API for this verification was added.

Here is [the discussion](http://forums.typemock.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=90116).

Comment: @AlexDn. Unfortunateley, no. In my case there was little crime in making the method public.

Comment: @AlexDn Typemock 7.5.2 now allows these checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Typemock v 7.5.2 API for this verification was added.

Here is [the discussion](http://forums.typemock.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=90116).